# Dash DataTable Filter is not working for numeric columns

Tags: python-3.x, plotly-dash

I created a table using Python Dash DataTable and added a filter to each column. The data table looks like this:

```
Text_Column   Numeric_Column
  abcde          12345
  dfjke          34928
```

Each column has a filter but it seems like the filter works only when the column has text values. It's not working for the numeric column. How do I make it to work for both text and numeric columns?

```
 dash_table.DataTable(
                      id="table",
                      columns=[
                               {"name": i, "id": i} for i in df.columns
                               ],
                      data=df.to_dict('records'),
                      filter_action="native",
                      sort_action="native",
                      style_table={
                                  "overflowX": "scroll",
                                                       },
                      row_selectable="multi",
                      style_cell={
                                  "height": "auto",
                                  "maxWidth": "200px",
                                  "whiteSpace": "normal",
                                  "font-family": "Arial",
                                  'textAlign': 'center',
                                                         },
                                                             
                                                                       
                                                            
                                                        )
                                                    ),
```

Comment: I can confirm this. I just had the same issue. I am not sure but it could be related to case sensitivity. See this bug report: https://github.com/plotly/dash/issues/1793

Answer (score 5):

So I just had the same issue. I fixed it by correctly setting the column's type to "numeric".

Like this:

```
columns = []
for col in df.columns:
    col_options = {"name": col, "id": col}
    if col == "MyNumericColumn":
        col_options["type"] = "numeric"
    columns.append(col_options)

my_table = dash_table.DataTable(id="table", columns=columns)
```

Please note that some filter operations currently seem to have an issue related to the case sensitivity of the column. See this bug report: https://github.com/plotly/dash/issues/1793

Answer (score 2):

So, a slight alternative if you wish to make any of your non string column to be filtered for any data you have.

```
columns = []
for col in df.columns:
    col_options = {"name": col, "id": col}
    for value in df[col]:
        if not (isinstance(value, str)):
            col_options["type"] = "numeric"
    columns.append(col_options)
return columns
```